# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Providers"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

hello this my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MedicallexiconProject-2012615153521;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false"/>
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

but when pulish on host rais this error
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

```
Line 44:     <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
Line 45:       <providers>
Line 46:         <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
Line 47:       </providers>
Line 48:     </membership>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should set Copy Local=true and ensure to use same version of .net framework.

Comment: How does that work? I tried to follow [these] instructions, but could not do so, as I did not see the "Show All Files" button

[these]:msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 35):

Use this NuGet command to install your DLL automatically:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core
```

For more information about Nuget Packages, read [this](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core) and [this one for a tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

Apparently you haven't deployed the `System.Web.Providers` assembly in your `bin` folder. Make sure it is marked with `Copy Local=true`?

Comment: All reference in my project is Copy Local=true

Comment: And have you verified that the assembly in question is present in the bin folder on your web server?

Comment: And still you get `The system cannot find the file specified`. I don't know what to say :-)

Comment: and this is my new error Method not found: 'Void System.ServiceModel.DiagnosticUtility.TraceHandledException(System.Exception, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType)'.

Comment: Yeah, you seem to have some assembly version mismatches.

Comment: Ensure that you have the same version of the framework and whatever 3rd party packages you are using on the server as on your local machine.

Answer (score 3):

In the Package Manager Console, I installed new packages as below and all was good in the world once again.

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core`

Comment: you need to do unInstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core 
and then
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had upgraded the version of Web Providers with NuGet and this broke my app. I had to go into web.config and manually update all assembly references in the provider sections to 2.0.0.0 instead of 1.0.0.0 since the new version of the System.Web.Providers assembly was 2.0.0.0.

Comment: To be clear, it actually added new blank, but duplicate provider entries that said 2.0.0.0. I deleted them and changed my existing ones to 2.0.0.0 and everything worked like a charm.