# HTML button sending input text data to ASP side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am working on a group project, and am trying to figure out ASP.net (hardly anyone in my group knows it, including me). My job is to make some text box and button such that, when the button is clicked, the text in the text box is processed and posted iff it has <= 140 characters.

I tried to write some jQuery that checks the text in the text box, and then sends it to the server for processing. The server is to save it to database, and post it to page, if it is no more than 140 characters long (this will be checked again).

Unfortunately, I run into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHgBl.jpg) error. I tried to contact my team members, but they are super busy with other issues. Here is my code:

Feed.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Feed.aspx.cs" Inherits="Feed_Feed" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<!-- This is here for test purpose -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#TweetButton').click(
                function()
                {
                    // get the text from the TweetBox
                    var status = $('#TweetBox').val();
                    // if it is 140 characters or less
                    if (status.length <= 140)
                    {
                        var data = JSON.stringify(status);
                        // send to the server page
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Feed.aspx.cs',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: data,
                            success: function(myStatus) 
                            {
                                $('#MyStatus').html(myStatus);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Tweet should contain no more than 140 characters");
                    }
                });
        });
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <h1>User Feed</h1>
    <p>
        <input id="TweetBox" type="text" /><input id="TweetButton" type="button" value="button" />

    </p>
    <div id="MyStatus"></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Feed.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Feed_Feed : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

The C# file is practically empty because I don't know how to handle the data being posted to the page (should it be in `Page_Load`?) I don't know what to do here...

Comment: So far this isn't even your code causing an issue, this is your web.config configuration being unhappy. Have you verified all of your connection info? According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16988949/3499931), you need to set `Copy Local = true`.

Comment: Where do I write that at? Are you (and they) talking about doing this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.90).aspx ?

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question? This is a serious one, as the answer that was linked to wasn't clear at all! Even worse was that, when I looked at the Microsoft website, their instructions weren't followable at all.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not going to post data to the asp.net server because you are just using regular HTML elements. In order to convert an html element to asp.net element, you need to use attribute `runat="server"`, so your markup would become :

```
<input id="TweetBox" type="text" runat="server" /><input id="TweetButton" type="button" value="button" runat="server" />
```

Alternately, to make the job simpler and have more flexibility on the asp.net controls ( like accessing additional properties ), you should strictly use asp.net core controls. So your new markup would look like :

```
<asp:TextBox id="TweetBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button id="TweetButton" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

In order to trigger a click event to post data onto the server ( codebehind ), you need to add the attributes `OnClick` to your button.

```
<asp:Button id="TweetButton" runat="server" OnClick="TweetButton_Click"></asp:Button>
```

In the codebehind (*.aspx.cs), you need to handle the event triggered by the button and check for the length of the text.

```
public partial class Feed_Feed : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void TweetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(TweetBox.Text.Length <= 140)
       {
         // Save data in the database.
       }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE :**

To work with ajax, you would need asp.net controls, so your markup would be

.ASPX =>

```
<input id="TweetBox" type="text" />
<input id="TweetButton" type="button" value="button" />



 <script>
    $().ready(function()
    {
    $('#TweetButton').click(function(){
                        // if it is 140 characters or less
                        if (status.length <= 140)
                        {
                            // send to the server page
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/Feed.aspx/SubmitTweet',
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                  data: "{'tweet':'" + $('#TweetBox').val() + "'}",
                                success: function(myStatus) 
                                {
                                    $('#MyStatus').html(myStatus.d);
                                },
                                error : function(er)
                                {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Tweet should contain no more than 140 characters");
                        }
                    });

    });
</script>
```

.ASPX.CS ( code-behind ) =>

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string SubmitTweet(string tweet)
    {
        // dummy function :
        return DataSubmit(tweet) ? "Data Was submitted" : "Error while submitting data";
    }

    public bool DataSubmit(string data)
    {        
        //call db connection and save the tweet
        // if successful , return true else false
    }
```

Comment: This is nice. Now, how precisely do I resolve my initial issue, so that I can see this work?

Comment: Please refer to the code under 'UPDATE'. I did not test it but hopefully should do the job. Put breakpoints on the methods in the code behind to check if ajax call went through.

Comment: That's not the part I was talking about. See my screenshot.

Comment: The referenced dll 'system.web.provider' is either missing from the references of your web or website project or is not the correct one. Go through this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx