# Config section 'system.web/profile' already defined

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had problem apparently with my web.config file earlier: [HTML button sending input text data to ASP side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402384/html-button-sending-input-text-data-to-asp-side/33402903#33402903) . I resolved it by actually [installing the System.Web.Providers package](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers). However, when I ran my code again, I get [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHG7h.jpg). It says this: `Config section 'system.web/profile' already defined. Sections must only appear once per config file. See the help topic <location> for exceptions`

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
            <clear />
            <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" /></providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <!--
                If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
                you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
                change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
                of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
          -->
        <!--
                If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
                you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
                change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
                of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
        -->
        <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
        <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
            <providers>
                <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
            <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=roosterdbdev;Database=RoosterDatabase;User Id=; Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and apparently, the problem is with line 50: `<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">`. However, when I comment that out, it complains about first tag before it.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You apparently have two "<profile>" tags defined in your web.config..

<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
And
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 (although I don't know how that matters, if at all).

Answer (score 0):

You have two `<profile ...>` and two `<sessionState ...>` sections in there.

Remove these and see how it goes.

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
     <providers>
           <clear />
           <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" />
     </providers>
</profile>
```

Further down

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
     <providers>
          <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" />
     </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Full version below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
            <clear />
            <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" /></providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <!--
                If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
                you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
                change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
                of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
          -->
        <!--
                If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
                you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
                change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
                of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
        -->
        <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
            <providers>
                <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
            <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=roosterdbdev;Database=RoosterDatabase;User Id=blah; Password=blah;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I comment that one out, and then the code complains about `<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">` on line 55. I comment that tag out, and I am back to square 1 (even though I installed `System.Web.Providers` already!

Comment: You also have two `<sessionState ...>` sections too. I've updated the answer

Comment: Complaint is now on line 30: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`